# Find all pairs (p,q) of real numbers such that whenever $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2 + px+q=0$ $\alpha^2-2$ is also root of the equation.

Tags: polynomials

> Find all pairs (p,q) of real numbers such that whenever $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2 + px+q=0$ $\alpha^2-2$ is also root of the equation.

My Approach:

I could not find any elegant method that is why I tried applying quadratic formula: the roots will be $\frac{-p±\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}$
Now we have 2 cases:

1. $$\left(\frac{-p+\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}\right) =\left (\frac{-p-\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}\right)^2 -2$$
2. $$\left(\frac{-p-\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{-p+\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}\right)^2-2$$

It's very tedious to solve these. I searched on Wolfram alpha and got these [I](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28-p-%E2%88%9A%28p%5E2%20-4q%29%29%2F2%29%5E2%20-2%20%3D%20%28%28-p%2B%E2%88%9A%28p%5E2-4q%29%29%2F2%29) [II](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28-p%2B%E2%88%9A%28p%5E2%20-4q%29%29%2F2%29%5E2%20-2%20%3D%20%28%28-p-%E2%88%9A%28p%5E2-4q%29%29%2F2%29)

Is there an elegant way to approach this problem?

Comment: May be without solving the equation. Notice that :
If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $x^2 + p x + q = 0$ then :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\alpha + \beta & = & -p \\[3mm]
\alpha \, \beta & = & q
\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be roots of this polynomial. If $\alpha=\beta$, then $\alpha^2-2=\alpha$, $\alpha=-1, 2$, and then $(p,q)=(2,1)$ or $(-4, 4)$, both choices work.

Suppose $\alpha\ne \beta$.

If $\alpha^2-2=\beta$, $\beta^2-2=\alpha$, then $(\alpha^2-2)^2-2=\alpha$, $\alpha^4-4\alpha^2-\alpha+2=0$, same for $\beta$. The polynomial $x^4-4x^2-x+2$ is $(x - 2)(x + 1)(x^2+x-1)$, $\alpha,\beta\in\{2, -1\}$ do not work. So $\{\alpha,\beta\}=\{(-1+\sqrt{5})/2, (-1-\sqrt{5})/2\}$. It works, $(p,q)=(1,-1)$.

Finally it could be that $\alpha^2-2=\alpha$ which means $\alpha\in\{-1,2\}$, and $\beta^2-2=\alpha$, so either $\alpha=-1$, $\beta^2-2=-1$, $\beta^2=1$, $\beta=1$ since $\beta\ne \alpha$, $(p,q)=(0,-1)$ or $\alpha=2$, $\beta^2-2=2$, $\beta=-2$, $(p,q)=(0,-4)$

Hence the **answer**: $(p,q)\in\{(-4,4), (2,1), (1,-1), (0,-1), (0,-4)\}$.

Comment: Does the question mean that $\alpha$ , $\beta$, $\alpha^2-2$ are the roots of $x^2 +px+q=0$? But since the equation is of degree $2$, it cannot have $3$ roots. Moreover, if we consider $(p,q) = (-418,7960)$ then the roots are $20$ and $398$ which satisfies the condition as $398 = 20^2 -2$.

Comment: You should read the question. $398^ 2-2 \ne 20$.

Comment: @markvs actually given answer is $6$

Answer (score 2):

For each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we can define a quadratic with zeros $x_1 = \alpha $ and $x_2 = \alpha^2 - 2$ by using Vieta's Theorem, which states $x^2+px+q$ with $-p = x_1 + x_2$ and $q = x_1 x_2$ has the desired zeros $x_1,x_2$. Hence for a given $\alpha$ the quadratic you are looking for is $x^2 - (\alpha^2 + \alpha - 2)x + (\alpha^3 - 2\alpha)$.

Edit: In order to find solutions s.t. it works indepently from the choice of the root, which we call $\alpha$, the both roots must satisfy $x_1^2 -2 = x_2$ and $x_2^2-2 = x_1$. How to go on from there is already shown in the answer by markvs.

Comment: Note that this solution is depentend on which of the zeros you define as $\alpha$.

Comment: Well spotted. It must work for both roots. Perhaps you'd like to change your answer.

Comment: This misses some solutions.